# jQuery - Detect Input Field Change On Iris Color Picker Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

I am trying to listen an input field change by its `id` where that input field is bound to iris color picker. Here is the sample code:

**HTML**

***input field***

```
<input type="text" id="input_id" class="elmnt_color"/>
```

***element to be changed***

```
<div id="box">Manipulate this!</div>
```

**jQUery**

***bind change***

```
$('.elmnt_color').iris({
    change: function(event, ui) {   
    $(this).siblings("input").change(); 
    }
});
```

***listening the input change through its `id`***

```
$("#input_id").on("change", function(){

   var style = '<style type="text/css">';
   style += '#box {background: ' + $(this).val() + '}';
   style += '</style>';

   $('head').append(style);

});
```

**PROBLEMS:**

- very slow
- 1 step too late. **e.g:** "when the iris color picker's color is changed
  from `blue` to `red`, the `#box` background color is still `blue`,
  instead of `red`. And so on.".

**QUESTION:**

What should I use to trigger `input field` change on iris color picker change instead of these codes:

```
change: function(event, ui) {   
$(this).siblings("input").change(); 
}
```

so I can get rid of the problems mentioned above.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

- There is no need to trigger and handle extra `input` `change` event.
- Element's CSS styles can be changed using jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/). It's definitely much better than adding `<style>` on every change.

So your code can be simplified into this one:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp6e0zra/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var box = $('#box');

    $('.elmnt_color').iris(
    {
        change: function(event, ui)
        {
            box.css("background", this.value);
        }
    });
});
```